# What happens to Mythos, Trauma, Keeper Action cards that have been used once?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

What happens to Mythos, Trauma, and Keeper Action cards that have been used by a Keeper?
Are they discarded to a discard pile, and can these discards later return back to the game when they run out?

Answer (score 4):

For Mythos Cards (Page 16):

> After playing a Mythos card, the keeper discards it to a faceup pile 
>   adjacent to the Mythos deck. If the Mythos deck runs out of cards, this 
>   discard pile is shuffled to create a new Mythos deck.

For Trauma Cards (Page 25):

> Each investigator may have a maximum of one injury and one 
>   insanity at any given time. If he receives a second card of the 
>   same type, the original card is discarded first.

Additionally, some injuries/insanities say discard immediately.

Under Component Limitations (Page 25):

> Decks of Cards: If a deck of cards runs out, the players 
>   shuffle the discard pile to create a new deck. The only 
>   exception is the Event deck, which always ends the game after 
>   the last card is drawn (as listed on the card).

For Keeper actions (Page 10):

> During this step, the keeper may resolve any number of these 
>   Keeper Action cards that he wishes (threat permitting). These 
>   actions are resolved one at a time by spending (discarding) the 
>   appropriate amount of threat (printed on the upper left corner of 
>   the Keeper Action card)

So Keeper Action cards don't get discarded ever, just the threat tokens. In fact, some keeper cards can be used multiple times in the same turn.